# Calling on a variable from one JS file in another file

Tags: javascript

So I have a file called `colorCodes.js` and in it I have the following information

```
const color = {
    red: 'FF3333',
    blue: '337DFF',
    green: '36FF33',
    orange: 'FFB833',
    purple: 'E633FF'
 };

 export default color;
```

in my second file `layout.js`, at the top I specify

`import color from './colorCodes';`

and then later on I want to call on those colors

```
const layout = {
    color.blue: navbar,
    color.red: background,
    color.orange: header,
    color.green: menu
 };
```

However, when I do this I get:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\...: Unexpected token, expected "," (40:10)
```

line 40 is: `color.blue: navbar,`
Wondering what I am doing wrong

Comment: You're not telling us which file the error is in, or which line is line 40.

Comment: just edited post

Comment: Still no sign of which line is line 40

Comment: just specified line 40

Comment: You have the property names and values reversed! … and you didn't before the edit!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have mixed up the keys and values in the `layout` object in the `layout.js` file. Try

```
import color from './colorCodes';

const layout = {
    navbar: color.blue,
    background: color.red,
    header: color.orange,
    menu: color.green
};
```

Comment: thanks just fixed that issue. However, later on I try and use ```color.blue``` however, I get an error, but then I refer to it's hex code I don't I'm confused why that may be happening